# Angular 4. I can not use Autocomplete - primeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, autocomplete

I am learning to use Angular 4, and in my effort to learn I want to install the Autocomplete element of PrimeNG and get the following error:
[image]

My project is basic and I have the following:

**autocomplete.component.ts**

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AutocompleteService } from '../../servicios/autocomplete.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html'
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

   text: string;
   results: string[];

   search(event) {
      console.log( event.query )
      //   this.mylookupservice.getResults(event.query).then(data => {
      //       this.results = data;
      //   });
   }

  constructor( private _autocompleteService:AutocompleteService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**autocomplete.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AutocompleteService {
   datos:any[] = [];
   urlBusqueda:string = "http://localhost:3000/consultas/";

   constructor( private http:Http ) {  }

   getDatos(termino:string){
      console.log( termino );

      // let query = `${ termino }`
      // let url = this.urlBusqueda + query;
      // return {};
      // console.log( url );
   }

}
```

Besides, I have referenced the component and service in app.module.ts. What I can be doing wrong?

Comment: You have to reference `autocompleteModule` in your own module, where you already put your components. You put it in the `imports` property of the Module decorator, and in the `exports` too if you want to use it in a shared module.

Comment: you didnt `import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/primeng';` to your `app.module`

Comment: Oh, I did not know that I also had to do that in the app.module.ts. Thank you very much, now it has worked!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions above didn't work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166616/10239655) did work - I needed **FormsModule** added to my shared module, e.g.:

```
//...
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
//...
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    //...
    FormsModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    //...
 ]
//...
```