# primeng autocomplete functionality is not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I have added the AutoCompleteModule in `app.module.ts` file.

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/autocomplete';
```

But autocomplete is not working as expected. I am getting below error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-autoComplete'.
1. If 'p-autoComplete' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-autoComplete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I am using primeng latest version.

I have tried adding autocomplete module in `app.module.ts`. After this I rebuild the application but still it is giving above error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: NgModule will have a section for `imports: []`, have you added Autocomplete there?

Comment: Yes. I have added

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to add **FormsModule** in `app.module.ts` file. Then it will work.

```
import { FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
<p-autoComplete  ... [(ngModel)]="WHATEVER" ...></p-autoComplete>
```

That's how you use ngModel with primeng components.